# Editing an .rpt file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

A company developed a small web interface written in VB.net to query a database and produce reports. The interface uses `CrystalDecisions.Shared` library. In the code, it references this:

```
 If rbExportType.SelectedValue = "PDF" Then
    Dim sda As New DB2DataAdapter(cmd)
    ReportName = "Reports/R002.rpt"
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath(ReportName), CrystalDecisions.[Shared].OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
    sda.Fill(ds.tbl_R002)
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    rpt.SetParameterValue(0, ddDatabase.SelectedItem.Text)
    ExporttoPDF()
 Else
```

Now, the users have asked me to add a simple field to the report, `Date`. I've edited the query to pull this data, but when I run the report the `Date` field is not shown on the report. I'm assuming that the actual .rpt file has to be edited to include this field on the report.

When trying to edit `Reports/R002.rpt` in a text editor, there are just numbers/symbols.

How can I edit this .rpt file? The version of Visual Studio 2010 has past it's trial.

Comment: Buy a copy of Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has (or had) a Crystal Reports editor built in. I couldn't find it just now in my Visual Studio 2012 install, so it's possible they dropped it in favor of their own Reporting Services platform, but I might just have missed it. If you can't find the editor in your Visual Studio 2010 copy, try downloading an older version of Visual Studio.

**Update:**

A quick Google search indicates that it's simply distributed separately now.
Here's the VS2012 version: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074
Here's the VS2010 version: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Answer (score 0):

CrystalReports is a proprietary software and wouldn't be part of the default VS package.

And yes, in order to add a field to the report, you would have to edit the report itself. Its not that big of a deal, if you have a copy of the CrystalReport software.

Comment: But SAP does give away a free copy of Crystal Reports for Visual Studio. See the links in Joel's answer.